# back to default apache 2.4.41 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, apache2, ppa

How to back from apache **2.4.46** (*ppa-ondrej-apach2*) to default Ubuntu 20.04 apache **2.4.41** without remove apache and installing again?

Is it possibible? To recompile apache?

Answer (score 0):

You have to purge [the PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2) from which this package was installed. Use commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get udpate
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

Comment: What if I purge ppa:ondrej/apache2 - is it remove apache2 from Ubuntu too? I have mod_tiles and don't want remove apache2 only downgrade it to default.

Comment: Backup these files and package names first. Then downgrade.